# Removing a square root of both sides of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wondered if it was possible, in an equation such as this one : 
$$
\sqrt{x} = \sqrt{1 + 2} 
$$
to transform it into something like this, removing both square roots :
$$
x = 1 + 2
$$

Is this mathematically correct or not ?

Comment: This is true, but as to whether or not there are more solutions depends on if the given operators/functions are one-to-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. If two numbers are equal, then so are their squares. So you can square the equation and keep the equality. And, by definition of square root $(\sqrt b)^2=b$ for any $b$ (we of course need $b\geq0$ for the root to be meaninful).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much !